# Linq query from user input

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm new to linq and I just ran into a usage I don't understand. In ADO .Net, SQL statements were strings. When the user's input impacted the query, it was easy enough to build the string for the SQL based on the user's selection of checkboxs or drop down lists.

In my current application I have three different drop down boxes where the user can select various values for their query. Let's say each drop down has 10 values. It's very easy to say a separate linq query for each possible combination is not practical.

If I know the user has selected a value in a combobox, then I can easily code that into the linq query. But what if the user hasn't selected a value?

How do I handle a select criteria that may or may not be there?

Thanks

---

So based on the input I've written this;

```
private DataTable FilterDMRMarcIDs()
    {
        var tmpValue = dtDMRMarc.AsEnumerable();

        if (chekbCountry.Checked)
        {
            tmpValue = tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("Country") == cbCountry.SelectedItem);
        }
        if (chekbState.Checked){
            tmpValue = tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("State") == cbState.SelectedItem);
        }
        return tmpValue.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    }    // FilterDMRMarcIDs() ...
```

Where dtData is a datatable and cbCountry and cbState are comboboxs containing strings.

The problem is this only returns the first matching record and not all of the other matching records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What should happen in that scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having more details about your actual code.

`IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` can be built up easily.
Each operation generally returns another `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, so you can chain them as you would like.

Here's an example:

```
public IEnumerable<Value> GetValues(IEnumerable<Value> values, string filter1, string filter2, string filter3)
{
    if (filter1 != null)
        values = values.Where(v => v.Attribute1 == filter1)
    if (filter2 != null)
        values = values.Where(v => v.Attribute2 == filter2)
    if (filter3 != null)
        values = values.Where(v => v.Attribute3 == filter3)
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Do each of the values.where statements add upon each other? So if all three have non null values then the total statement would be equivalent to Where (v.Attribute1 = filter1 and v.Attribute2 = filter2 and v.Attribute3 = filter3)?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided what kind of information is stored in your combobox, and what kind of Collections with entities you have. For example by default(when user didn't selected any value), the values of each combobox has value = 0(default(int)), and Your entity(lets call it `Sample`) has 3 properties(int `age`, string `Name`, String `Surname`). Then you can do something similar:

```
  public IEnumerable<Sample> Filter(IEnumerable<Sample> collectionToFilter, int age, string name, string surname){
     if(!age.Equals(default(age))){
        collectionToFilter = collectionToFilter.Where(e=>e.Age==age);
     }
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)){
        collectionToFilter = collectionToFilter.Where(e=>e.Name==name);
     }
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(surname)){
        collectionToFilter = collectionToFilter.Where(e=>e.Surname==surname);
     }
     return collectionToFilter;
  }
```

And you handle on any combobox change and call `Filter` method. Thats it.
Each filter will be applied only when it will be set to `not default` value.

For example, if you will make the next call:

```
var someArray = Filter(someArray, 50, null, null);
```

In some array will be all entities which have `Age` == 50

```
var someArray = Filter(someArray, 50, "John", null);
```

In some array will be all entities which have `Age` == 50 and `Name` == John

etc...